# How can I pop to a view controller that exists on another stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

### Scenario

I'm currently on a view controller that's embedded in navigation controller, for the sake of this example, let's call this navigation controller `Hendrix`. I want to pop to another view controller, which is embedded in another navigation controller, let's call that navigation controller `Bowie`.

So I have something that looks like this:

`Stuff` - `Hendrix` - `VC` - `TargetVC` - `Bowie` - `VC` - `VC` - `CurrentVC`

### Problem

Naturally you want to look through your stack, find your view controller, then pop to it, but since `CurrentVC` exists on `Bowie`, and `TargetVC` exists on `Hendrix` they are on seperate stacks.

Comment: Can you create a segue between the two, or am I totally misinterpreting this?

Comment: Do you have a reference at all to that other VC? Because if you do, you should be able to call `otherVC.navigationController.popController` (pseudocode).

Comment: @JohnRamos that'll just add `TargetVC` to the current stack.

Comment: @sschale I don't have a reference, would that work though? Can you pop from a navigation controller that isn't on top?

Comment: Can you avoid the situation where you put a navigation controller on a navigation controller?  If not then you will need to get a reference to Hendrix so that you can pop to TargetVC.  If you are using storyboards then you can define an unwind segue method in `TargetVC` and invoke that from `CurrentVC`

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11 - having multiple Navs on top of each other is not a good idea, if this is entirely a linear flow of VCs. If there was only 1 Nav, you could access the nav stack and remove the desired VC. Also, you could use a delegate or singleton to store/pass reference to that VC.

Comment: Unfortunately the app is currently built that way, if I can't find a way around it I'll just have to restructure things. I believe it was built that way because it's not a linear flow.

Comment: Can you use an unwind segue?

Comment: I tried that, wasn't able to. But good suggestion 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this completely fits your case, but check out  [What's New in Storyboards - WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/215/) at time 28:30.

In their example, there's a Journal Navigation Controller and a Photo Navigation Controller.  The case given at 29:00 is that the user wants to go back from the Photo View Controller on the Photo Navigation Controller stack to the Journal Table View Controller on the Journal Navigation Controller stack.  This is done via a single segue.

By implementing `childViewControllerContainingSegueSource(_:)` it knows which view controller you're starting from (in your case the View Controller on the Hendrix stack).  It will then recursively look through the Hendrix stack and then up to any parent controller that contains both navigation controllers.  It will then find your other navigation controller (Bowie) and look through its children.  If it finds a View Controller that can perform the unwind segue, then the destination has been found and it will execute the segue.

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing in your case, but hopefully there is a parent VC that contains your two navigation controllers.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks man! Didn't know this was a thing.
I was at WWDC '14, shame I couldn't make it last year.

Comment: I've never been :(  Praying I get a ticket from the lottery this year!

Comment: Good luck with that :)